# I need help "quitting mail" on my Apple computer

Tags: macos

After I tried to use links in some websites, my Apple computer will not send the emails to those links nor will it allow me to quit mail. Since I cannot quit mail, I cannot get updates because the mail program interrupts the updates.  What do I need to do?

Comment: You tagged this as `ios` which somewhat conflicts with the question itself. Are you looking for a solution on an iPhone/iPad or on a Mac?

Answer (score 2):

Do you know about "Force Quit"? In any app, if you hold down the keys Command-Option-Escape, a window comes up with running apps where you can choose which one to Force Quit.

Post another question here if you need help with Mail.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can go for *activity monitor* and select mail then click on quit button (in case application not responding the quit button will be used as force quit as well).

To launch activity monitor, find activity in spot light, probably the first result will be *Activity Monitor* then click on it.
[image]